# How to Find UNIX Files in a Windows Environment

Tags: windows, unix, find

Is there a way to find UNIX files in a Windows environment?

I'm looking in a specific HUGE folder with dozens of sub-folders for all UNIX files in a Windows environment. I've done a few cursory searches, i.e., *.bashrc, but am not sure where to go from there. I don't see any obvious file extensions that would lend a clue either.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Unix/Linux doesn't use file extensions. And what do you mean by "Unix files" and why do you think you would find such things in a Windows environment?

Comment: It uses file extensions nearly as much as Windows does... it just doesn't have any which mean "this is a Unix file".

Comment: Generally *nix files are just text files.  Let's find a better way to search.  I assume you have the folder somewhere on your HD.  If you know it's huge in terms of total file size, then run WinDirStat as Administrator and you can search graphically.  If you know it's huge in terms of number of files in a particular folder, or in terms of deepest-nested folder, then there's probably ways to search for that, that I don't know off the top of my head.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage *I assume you have the folder somewhere on your HD*... Well, I don't until I have confirmation the OP knows the said folder should be there, not that they *think* something *should* be there. The way the question is written makes me suspect of some kind of X-Y problem.

Comment: @MichaelBay, you're right, he said Windows environment, not on a particular PC.  Searching a whole network of PCs is harder and should involve IT personnel.  The first question the IT person will ask is "Do you have permission to view these files"

Comment: What is the UNIX disk format? ext*x*? NTFS (if shared with Windows)? other?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about the files created by Windows Subsystem for Linux.

The files are located at:

> C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState`

Be sure to replace `yourusername` with the appropriate folder.

This folder might be different if you install one of the other Linux distros, but all will be under the `AppDatap directory.

Be careful in this directory tree, Windows and Linux treat files differently and modifying them in Windows can cause issues.